# AmazonIdentityManagementServiceClient is too much time consuming

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, service, client

I am initializing Amazon client from a web-api. The following code is almost taking over 1 min.

```
Amazon.IdentityManagement.AmazonIdentityManagementServiceClient client = new Amazon.IdentityManagement.AmazonIdentityManagementServiceClient(cred);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked this issue reproduce only when I run AWS services from my local source code in debug mode, while compiled and production environment it is better.